# stringstream peek() error C3867

Tags: string, visual-studio, c++11, header-files, peek

I have method of a class, that accepts a key variable and looks up the key in an underdone map.  The Value is a string `example: "12132, jack_arog, 1990:12:8:3:25:3"`; method will use `peek()` in stringstream to recognize `','` and `' '` to ignore them and put the rest in a vector. Afterwards method will assign members of vector to attributes of an object.

Error is recieve during compilation:

```
if (ss.peek() == ',' || ss.peek == ' ')
    ss.ignore();

Error   C3867   'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::peek': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

I looked up this error and most say you forgot () when calling a function, however i do not believe this is my problem.

Method:

```
void Account::find_account(std::string name, std::string ID)
{
    std::string key = name + "," + ID;
    Account new_account;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator got = map.find(key);

    if (got == map.end())
        std::cout << "not found";
    else
    {
        std::string my_string = got->second;

        std::vector<std::string> holder;
        std::stringstream ss(my_string);
        std::string i;

        while (!my_string.empty() && ss >> i)
        {
            holder.push_back(i);

            if (ss.peek() == ',' || ss.peek == ' ')
                ss.ignore();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < holder.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i = 0)
                new_account.ID = holder.at(i);
            if (i = 1)
                new_account.account_holder = holder.at(i);
            if (i = 2)
            {
                std::string::size_type sz;
                new_account.amount_available = std::stof(holder.at(i), &sz);
            }
            if (i = 3)
            {
                new_account.date_created = holder.at(i);
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `ss.peek == ' '` is missing the `()` ?

Comment: ooOOOOOmmmGGGGG, thank youuuuu

Comment: :-p that's just a sign you've been coding too long.  Break time! lol

Comment: I know :D, I probably should redo this method all together, its very ugly.

Comment: I've seen way worse on SO.  I think it looks pretty good :)

Comment: hey please post an answer, so i can pick it?

Comment: I don't feel my find had enough substance to make an answer but I appreciate it.  Feel free to check one of my other answers for one you like.  Forgot to upvote your Q before though; very well written and clear.  Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I looked up this error and most say you forgot () when calling a function, however i do not believe this is my problem."*

How can you say that when your compiler tells you that the error is exactly on this line?  Moreover it is telling you that the error is specifically tied to your (ab)use of peek, I quote:

```
"...peek': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

I translate:  The compiler thinks you are **not** trying to call peek, since you did not type the required () to do so.  So, if you are by any chance trying to get the function address, you should prepend & to the function name for the syntax to be correct.

Computers are dumb, I'll give you that, but they are rarely wrong.